# correct way to return a json_object as an array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

I have an array populated using an sql statement in the following manner:

```
$index = 0;

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $bookname[$index] = ($row['Bookname']);
    $subjectname[$index] = ($row['SubjectName']);
    $index++;
}
```

When I go to echo json encode the Arrays I get a blank [] when I know it has been populated which is really weird. 
Am I doing anything wrong in my context

```
echo json_encode($Bookname,$SubjectName);
```

Comment: Second param of `json_encode()` sets options on how to encode the data. Do not use some of your data in that place or you'll ge t really weired results. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @maxhb even with one param lets use $bookname it still gives [] when I test echo $Bookname[2]; it works perfectly fine and prints that element!

Comment: use `var_dump(json_encode($Bookname));` or `var_dump(json_encode($SubjectName));` you can not print an `object` or `array` using `echo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) as like that:

```
<?php
$index = 0;
$data = array();
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $data[$index]['bookname'] = $row['Bookname'];
    $data[$index]['subjectname'] = $row['SubjectName'];
    $index++;
}
json_encode($data); // encode your array
?>
```

Comment: Still getting [] I understand that two params shouldn't be used but even with one param nothing happens

Comment: @EoinÓCribín: please use print_r($row); inside the loop and share the result.

Comment: Nothing printed at all. but if I test using my original code and say for example: echo  $bookname[0] after the loop I get a resut

Comment: @EoinÓCribín: u can not use $booksname[0] with my example... well, please use print_r($data); after loop (outside the loop)

Comment: just a blank array (Array ( )) prints I was sure data was going into it.

Comment: @EoinÓCribín: one more testing plz, $data['bookname'][] = $row['Bookname'];
    $data['subjectname'][] = $row['SubjectName'];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103114/discussion-between-devpro-and-eoin-o-cribin).

Comment: @EoinÓCribín sorry I didn't chk the chat good to see u solve it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
       $index = 0;
       $data = array();
       while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
        $data['Bookname'][$index] = $row['Bookname'] 
        $data['SubjectName'][$index] = $row['SubjectName'];
        $index++;

       }
       echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have passed two parameter while calling `json_encode` function. You batter combine two array in one. Then call the `json_encode` function like `json_encode($combinedArray)`

Comment: second param of json_encode is for behaviour http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: _It takes only one parameter_ ??? I doubt on this line of your answer... see @devpro 's comment.

Comment: and third param is depth :) brother