# Empty list but scope have json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html, css

I'm developing an app with HTML5, CSS3, AngularJS and Ionic.
I'm getting data from my server in JSON format. The scope have the object (I debugged it).

But the list is empty (never show me the information)
This is the part of the code from the HTML file:

```
<ion-view view-title="Mis Notas">
<ion-content ng-controller="VersionCtrl">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item" ng-repeat="version in versiones">
            <h2>{{version.success}}</h2>
            <p>{{version.version}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</ion-content>
<div class="bar bar-footer bar-stable">
    <a class="button button-positive icon-left ion-compose" href="/#/create">Agregar</a>
</div>
</ion-view>
```

And the controller have this:

**app.js**

```
 app.controller('VersionCtrl',['$http','$scope', function($http, $scope){
    $http.get('http://myhosting.com/version.php')
    .success(function(result){
        $scope.versiones = result;
    })
    .error(function(result){
        alert('Algo anda mal...:'+result);
    });
}]);
```

When I debugged result return this:

**result = Object {success: 1, version: "V 3.0"}**

I'm new in Javascript, angular and Ionic. Please, considerer that.

If i put:

```
<h2>{{versiones.success}}</h2>
<p>{{versiones.version}}</p>
```

The list show me the data. But I don't know if the json have 1 item or 100 items. So..

Thanks

Comment: You may wish to read up more about objects in general http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

It looks like you are being returned an individual object. Brackets would signify an array of objects which would need to be iterated.

Comment: I think your result should be [{success: 1, version: "V 3.0"}], you need to return an array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [correct way to return a json\_object as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313959/correct-way-to-return-a-json-object-as-an-array)